# How to check angle in range?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

For example: angle 10 is cross 270 ~ 390 , because 270 to 390 is inclue 270 ~ 360 and 0 ~ 30.

```
InRange(0, 180, 90);//true;
InRange(180, 270, 90);//false;
InRange(270, 390, 10);//false; <== but this is in range , How to fix?
```

And my method:

```
public bool InRange(int start, int end, int angle)
{
    if (angle >= start && angle <= end)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: My -1 because you give no real explanation about the ranges to be supported.

Comment: See my answer. It is guaranteed to be 100% correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When normalizing, use `%` (or my own `Mod` for the sake of reinventing the wheel) and `if` because they are cheaper than looping with `while`.

```
class Program
{
    static int Mod(int x, int n)
    {
        if (x < 0)
            return -Mod(-x, n);
        if (n < 0)
            return Mod(x, -n);

        int m = x / n;
        return x - m * n;
    }

    // Normalize x to be between left inclusive and right exclusive.
    static int Normalize(int left, int right, int x)
    {
        int period = right - left;
        // int temp = x % period;
        int temp = Mod(x, period); // reinvent the wheel!
        if (temp < left)
            return temp + period;
        if (temp >= right)
            return temp - period;
        return temp;
    }

    // Test whether x between start and end inclusive
    static bool InRange(int start, int end, int x)
    {
        start = Normalize(0, 360, start);
        end = Normalize(0, 360, end);
        x = Normalize(0, 360, x);

        if (start <= end)
            return start <= x && x <= end;

        else
            return !(end < x && x < start);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(InRange(0, 180, 90)); // must be true
        System.Console.WriteLine(InRange(180, 270, 90)); //  must be false
        System.Console.WriteLine(InRange(270, 390, 10)); // must be true
        System.Console.WriteLine(InRange(270, 180, 90)); // must be true        
        System.Console.WriteLine(InRange(270, 270, -90)); // must be true        
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it's worked , and avoid while

Comment: Ok your solution is totally corret , So you got this accept thanks.

Comment: @TimChang: If you use `int temp = x % period;` instead of `int temp = Mod(x, period);`, you can remove `Mod`. As a result, the code becomes much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that range is normalized (390>270)

Find middle angle `m = (270+390)/2` and half-angle `h = (390-270)/2`

Compare cosine of difference of needed angle `a` and middle one `m`  with cosine of half-angle `h`  (convert degrees to radians if needed in your language). This approach helps to avoid problems with periodicity etc

```
if cos(a - m) >= cos(h)  
    {a inside the range}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it's worked , and very smart.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that `0° ≤ start < 360°` and `0° < end - start ≤ 360°`.

There are two cases:

- `end < 360°`: the condition is `start ≤ angle mod 360° ≤ end`.
- `end ≥ 360°`: the condition is `not (end - 360° ≤ angle mod 360° ≤ start)`.

CAUTION: the usual `%` operator does not perform a true modulo operation for the negative argument.

Comment: when start =270 ,end = 390 , target = 10 , in `end ≥ 360° case`  , ` 390 -360 <= 10%360 <= 270 ` <-- it's not working.

Comment: @TimChang: my bad, the second condition must be complemented.

Answer (score 1):

Move all the angles to within a consistent circle:

```
static bool InR(int f, int t, int w){
  f%=360;
  t%=360;
  w%=360;

  while(f<0) f += 360;
  while(t<f) t += 360;
  while(w<f) w += 360;
  
    
  return f <= w && w <= t;
}
```

Comment: There is a much cheaper way to normalize (especially when the test number is huge), see my answer. :-)

Comment: thanks , it's worked , this code look so clean.